# replace() string in python

Tags: python, string, replace

I want to remove ">>> " and "...     " form the doc using `replace()` but its not working for me (it prints the same doc). Check the last three lines of code.

```
doc = """
>>> from sets import Set
>>> engineers = Set(['John', 'Jane', 'Jack', 'Janice'])
>>> programmers = Set(['Jack', 'Sam', 'Susan', 'Janice'])
>>> managers = Set(['Jane', 'Jack', 'Susan', 'Zack'])
>>> employees = engineers | programmers | managers           # union
>>> engineering_management = engineers & managers            # intersection
>>> fulltime_management = managers - engineers - programmers # difference
>>> engineers.add('Marvin')                                  # add element
>>> print engineers 
Set(['Jane', 'Marvin', 'Janice', 'John', 'Jack'])
>>> employees.issuperset(engineers)     # superset test
False
>>> employees.update(engineers)         # update from another set
>>> employees.issuperset(engineers)
True
>>> for group in [engineers, programmers, managers, employees]: 
...     group.discard('Susan')          # unconditionally remove element
...     print group
...
Set(['Jane', 'Marvin', 'Janice', 'John', 'Jack'])
Set(['Janice', 'Jack', 'Sam'])
Set(['Jane', 'Zack', 'Jack'])
Set(['Jack', 'Sam', 'Jane', 'Marvin', 'Janice', 'John', 'Zack'])
"""

doc.replace(">>> ","")
doc.replace("...     ","")
print doc
```

So, can any one give a better solution for removing ">>> " and "...     ".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Strings are immutable in python, so `str.replace`(and all other operations) simply return a new string and the original one is not affected at all:

```
doc = doc.replace(">>> ","")      # assign the new string back to `doc`
doc = doc.replace("...     ","")
```

help on `str.replace`:

```
>>> print str.replace.__doc__
S.replace(old, new[, count]) -> string
```

> Return a **copy** of string S with all occurrences of substring old
>   replaced by new.  If the optional argument count is given, only the
>   first count occurrences are replaced.

Comment: although this answer solves the OP's particular problem, in general `replace` is a wrong tool for that (think `>>> print ">>>foo"`).

Answer (score 3):

`replace()` does not modify the string, it returns a new string with the modification.

So write: `doc = doc.replace(">>> ","")`

Answer (score 1):

Python strings are immutable so `.replace` returns a new string instead of mutating the original as you have presumed.

```
doc = doc.replace(">>> ","").replace("...     ","")
print doc
```

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Ok fixed but I would have changed it happily without the DV ;) Also you are always free to edit things such as that in. IIRC that is not a valid reason to downvote since my answer is and was *useful* but no hard feelings here